# Can't log in with casperJS in webshot() in R

Tags: javascript, r

I'm trying to login with casperJS in webshot() in R, but my code doesn't work. Anything I'm doing wrong below?

```
library(webshot)
webshot('https://suite.searchmetrics.com/en/auth/login', zoom = 1.3,
        eval = "
      this.wait(5000);
      var url = 'https://suite.searchmetrics.com/en/auth/login';
      casper.start(url, function() {
        console.log('page loaded');
        this.fill('form#loginForm', { 
          mail: 'my_email', 
          password:  'my_password'
        }, true);
      });")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a problem in the webshot() package. The 'eval' argument was not being executed. I created an issue on the package repo and it should be fixed now.